# Error sending ether to a a smart contract deployed in ropsten with web3 with python

Tags: ether, ropsten, web3.py, infura, python

I am trying to send ether to a smart contract deployed on ropsten via infura, but I am having some problems in txn.

The error is "Error in Txn: Reverted".
[image: Here you can see the attemps to sen ether and the errors]

The sender account has enought ether to afford the transaction so I dont understand what is failing.

```
def default_reward():
    
    amount_in_ether=2
    amount_in_wei = wb3.toWei(amount_in_ether,'ether')

    acct = wb3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(config.ADMIN_KEY)
    
    txn_dict = {
            'to': config.audacoin_contract_address,
            'value': amount_in_wei,
            'gas': 4465030,
            'gasPrice': wb3.toWei('21', 'gwei'),
            'from': acct.address,
            'nonce': wb3.eth.getTransactionCount(acct.address),
            
    }
    
    signed_txn = acct.signTransaction(txn_dict)
    
    txn_hash = wb3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    
    txReceipt = wb3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(txn_hash)

    return "Sended"
```

This is the method I use and it executes normally, I mean, without any errors.

I supouse that I commit an error declaring txn_dict but I dont know which.

Thanks very much for your help!

PS: I connect to ropsten via Infura.

Comment: Side note: you only need 21000 gas (not 4465030, as you've used).

Comment: Side note #2: current price on Ropsten is 1 Gwei (so your price of 21 Gwei seems awfully high).

Comment: Side note #3: `wb3.eth.sendRawTransaction` returns a `Promise` object, which you should either resolve or await for completion of. So `txn_hash ` doesn't seem like what you think it is.

Comment: @goodvibration I have tried it but it does not funct, but thanks a lot. I think I found the solution.

Comment: web3py does not use python promises yet, so the side note #3 is not really valid. See the code by yourself: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/blob/fc5b16587938d209b9fdf1e04da1e29b70594336/web3/eth.py#L314

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contract can't recieve funds by dafault. To make it possible you need to add a payable fallback function to the contract code. It should looks like this:

`function () external payable {}`

Comment: Thank you, I made all the method but I forgot the most impotant. Thanks a lot.